# How can I run the fast-api server using Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, fastapi

I have a simple API function as below,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

I am starting the server using **`uvicorn`** command as,

```
uvicorn main:app
```

Since we are not calling any python file *directly*, it is not possible to call `uvicorn` command from Pycharm.

So, **How can I run the fast-api server using Pycharm?**

Comment: There is an easy workaround by `pip install uvicorn` and then running it as a python module: `python -m uvicorn main:app`. Works like a... (Py)Charm.

Answer (score 196, accepted):

### Method-1: Run FastAPI by calling [`uvicorn.run(...)`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/debugging/#call-uvicorn)

In this case, your minimal code will be as follows,

```
# main.py

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Normally, you'll start the server by running the following command,

```
python main.py
```

#### Pycharm Setup

For this setup, and now, you can set the script path in Pycharm's config

[image: Pycharm-uvicorn.run]

#### Notes

- Script Path: path to the FastAPI script
- Python Interpreter: Choose your interpreter/virtual environment
- Working Directory: Your FastAPI project root

---

### Method-2: Run FastAPI by calling [`uvicorn`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#run-it) command

In this case, your minimal code will be as follows,

```
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
```

Normally, you'll start the server by running the following command,

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

#### Pycharm Setup

For this setup, and now, you can set the script path in Pycharm's config

[image: Pycharm-uvicorn.command]

#### Notes

- Module name: set to `uvicorn`
- [Optional] Script:  Path to `uvicorn` binary. You will get the path by executing the command, ***`which uvicorn`*** , inside your environment. ([See this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BE9I.png))
- Parameters: The actual parameters of `uvicorn` command
- Python Interpreter: Choose your interpreter/virtual environment
- Working Directory: Your FastAPI project root

Comment: The problem is that you can't deploy to production this way because you can't really pass other parameters to uvicorn...say "workers", etc.  At least I can't get it to work.

Comment: Also, this is *not for production*. Suppose if you want to update the number of workers, you need to update your code, which is of course not a good idea. That's why unicorn supports the commandline setup.

Comment: BTW, the `uvicorn.run(...)` supports all the args supported by the commandline

Comment: You can pass in args via pycharm and dynamically configure uvicorn all args supported via config = Config(app, **kwargs)

Comment: Could you explain why that matter here? Sorry that I didn't get your point @TimothyMugayi

Comment: I was looking for this solution for the past 2 (two) years now :)

Comment: Is running on `0.0.0.0` safe?  I'm a novice but someone might have told me at some point, "don't do that".  I changed it to `localhost` and it works.

Answer (score 53):

You can do it without adding code to main.py

1. In `target to run` instead of `Script path` choose `Module name`
2. In `Module name` type `uvicorn`
3. In parameters `app.main:app --reload --port 5000`

[image]

Comment: Awesome, couln't find an answer anywhere else on how to debug AND reload at the same time

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion as it is the only one that lets you use `--reload`

Comment: Ensure to check working directory if you get 'app' module not found.

Comment: Server log output is better using this method, it should be the best answer.

Answer (score 13):

Try to call uvicorn inside your code. e.g:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, log_level="info")
```

[Reference](https://www.uvicorn.org/)

Comment: This seems more like a dev setting/tweak, is it acceptable to push this code out to prod environment?

Comment: @Neeraj, there is [no difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63177681/is-there-a-difference-between-running-fastapi-from-uvicorn-command-in-dockerfile).

Answer (score 5):

Another example, this might be helpful to someone.

```
# fastapi_demo.py

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response

app = FastAPI()

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def demo(request):
    try:
        print(request)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    return Response(content='OK')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app='fastapi_demo:app')
```

Comment: this results in the fastapi_demo to be run twice. If you have a (for example) global variable it will be initialized

Comment: Thanks, @Coco to identify my mistake. It was running twice just because of misconfiguration. Actually, I have added `reload=True` and it leads to double initialization. To avaid that you must add `reload_dirs=['/app_dir_name',]`. But, this approach is not wrong to run app by PyCharm. [Check this](https://www.uvicorn.org/#running-programmatically) FYI

Comment: you would need to run `uvicorn.run(app)` instead, that'd not start the app twice