# is there a difference between running fastapi from uvicorn command in dockerfile and from pythonfile?

Tags: python, docker, fastapi, uvicorn

I am running a fast api and when i was developing i had the following piece of code in my app.py file

code in app.py:

```
import uvicorn


if __name__=="__main__":
    uvicorn.run("app.app:app",host='0.0.0.0', port=4557, reload=True, debug=True, workers=3)
```

so i was about to run `CMD ["python3","app.py"]` in my Dockerfile.

on the fastapi example they did something like this :

```
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]
```

I want to know what is the difference between these two methods as i think both of them will work.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### Update (on 2022-12-31)

As an update from *@Marcelo Trylesinski*, from [uvicorn `v 0.19.0`](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/releases/tag/0.19.0), the `--debug` flag was removed (Ref [#1640](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/pull/1640)).

---

**No, there is no difference.**

The commadline run method (`uvicorn app.main:app`) and executing the app.py using python command (`python app.py`) are the same. Both methods are calling the [**`uvicorn.main.run(...)`**](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/918722aef95de009fa20de7701286696455f0440/uvicorn/main.py#L342) function under the hood.

In other words, the **`uvicorn`** command is a *shortcut* to the **`uvicorn.run(...)`** function.

So, in your case the function call

```
uvicorn.run("app.app:app",host='0.0.0.0', port=4557, reload=True, debug=True, workers=3)
```

can be done by uvicorn commandline as,

```
uvicorn app.app:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4557 --reload --debug --workers 3
```

---

### Side Notes

The ***--debug*** option is hidden from the [command line options help page](https://www.uvicorn.org/#command-line-options), but it can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/918722aef95de009fa20de7701286696455f0440/uvicorn/main.py#L81). Thus, it feels running the app using `uvicorn` command can be considered as a ***production thing.***

Comment: The `--debug` option no longer exists, the answer can be updated. ~ maintainer of uvicorn here.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is **no**. There will be no difference in app, deploying with **Docker** just making it **easier**, without Docker you need to run it with **ASGI** compatible server like Uvicorn, also you might want to set up some tooling to make sure it is restarted automatically if it stops or crashes. Instead of trying to handle it manually, a Docker image can handle all these jobs automatically.