# Pycharm and Fastapi - No Package Found Error

Tags: pycharm, fastapi

Hello im trying to complete my first fastapi project.

When i add to fastapi to requirements.txt i got and error in pycharm editor. (package not found) any idea ?

How it looks

[image: 1]

Error Message

[image: 2]

Comment: seems like fastapi was not installed, try pip install fastapi

Comment: i already installed fastapi and i tried pip install but not worked for me.

Comment: see if this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62856818/how-can-i-run-the-fast-api-server-using-pycharm

Comment: no way doesnt work for me. my main problem ist fast api already installed on my project but pycharm doesnt see it

Comment: Any progress on that matter, it would be terrific if there is solution for it.

Answer (score -1):

Run in the pycharm terminal the command:

`pip install fastapi`

Comment: i already installed fastapi and i tried pip install but not worked for me